# SSIS Network Path Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an SSIS job (2008) which uses variables set up in the SSIS Configurations database table. One of these variables is the folder path which the job should look in for files.

When I have this set to a local path on the same computer it works fine, e.g. d:\Processing\

but if I change this to a network path e.g.  \\networklocation\Processing, it fails with the following error

Flat File Connection Manager - Description - the flat file "\\networklocation\processing\" specified in the connection was not valid. End Error. Code 0xC001401D. Failed Validation 0xC001401E

File name property is not valid. The file name is a device or contains invalid characters.

I've read various problems about network paths and SSIS - is there a solution for it?

Comment: I should add that if I execute this within SSIS using the network path, it works fine.

Comment: Possibly permissions - maybe being run by a different user when done as a job compared to running through SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I made a new Credential on the DB and then a new Proxy and I run the job as that user

That seemed to work ok - must have been permissions that prevented it from seeing the network folder